# TClientDataSet.Cancel Loses TDBMemo Values

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tclientdataset, data-loss

I have a form with the following controls: `TDBEdit`, `TDBMemo`, `TDataSource`, `TClientDataSet`

If the user edits the fields and then clicks a button on the form that simply calls the `MyCDS.Cancel` method (to cancel the edits), the `TDBEdit` fields revert to their original values, but the `TDBMemo` fields are not reverted (they are set to blank values).

The `TClientDataSet` is populated from a MSSQLServer 2008 database.  The `TDBEdit` fields are `nvarchar(255)` in the database, and the `TDBMemo` are `nvarchar(max)` or `xml` fields.

Looking at the values in the Debug Inspector (ctrl+F7, MyCDS.FieldByName('afield'), Inspect) shows the following for one of the `nvarchar(max)` fields:

- DataSize = 0
- DataType = ftWideMemo
- Size = 1

This is the same for all of the `nvarchar(max)` and `xml` fields whether or not the underlying field has data or not.

It appears that there is an incompatibility between the `nvarchar(max)` (which is treated as a `ftWideMemo`) and the `TDBMemo` control.

Has anyone seen issues like this before?  Do you have any suggestions how to resolve it?

Comment: What is the field type the `TDBMemo` is connected to? Also, two thoughts: 1) Why aren't you simply using `SysUtils.Abort;`, since the exception is supposed to be silent? and 2) Wouldn't it just be easier to disable the ability to navigate away once editing has begun until they've either saved or cancelled the edit?

Comment: @Ken - I revised the question.  it now reflects my latest troubleshooting.

Comment: Nicely revised. (+1, BTW - should have done that before.) I don't have SQL Server 2008 on this machine, so I won't be able to try and reproduce the issue until tomorrow; I'm afraid I don't have any suggestions at this point. There are several people that frequent Delphi questions here that are pretty knowledgeable about `TClientDataSet`, so you'll probably get an answer pretty quickly. If not, I'll look into it first thing tomorrow if I can.

Comment: I'm going to work on a standalone simple app to try and reproduce it as well.  The current bug shows up in my client app that pulls data through a DataSnap server.  So there are several more variables involved.  I need eliminate those that aren't a factor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone in interested, the problem is a bug in the `TClientDataSet` component.  The problem only occurs when you clone a dataset, don't have a `Provider` and turn `LogChanges` off.  If you edit a record on the cloned dataset and then cancel the edit, then any *memo* fields lose their values.

Since you don't necessarily use a `Provider` in file-based applications, it doesn't always make sense to enable `LogChanges`.  However, to work around the limitation with *memo* fields, you can leave `LogChanges` on, and then call `MergeChangeLog` after operations that change the cloned dataset.

I created a program that demonstrates the issue.  See the Embarcadero incident QC#110511.